# How to investigate 100% CPU load for 15 minutes on random days

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, cloudflare, performance-monitoring

"I have a server that runs a website on Apache2 and is behind Cloudflare. The server's normal load, according to 'htop', is 10%. However, at random days/times, the server load spikes up to 100%, causing the website to go down for approximately 15 minutes. I have learned about this issue from AWS EC2 status monitoring. Since I am not online at all times, I can't see the 'htop' output when the high load occurs.

To investigate the issue further, I need to collect the following data:

1. CPU usage by different processes at the time of the crash: I need to monitor the CPU usage of various processes running on the server during the time of the crash. This data will help me identify which process is causing the high load.
2. The number of HTTP requests and the URL visited at the end of the time of the crash: I need to collect the number of HTTP requests made to the server during the time of the high load, as well as the URLs that were visited. This data will help me identify if there is a specific URL or set of URLs that are causing the high load.

Once I have collected this data, I can analyze it to identify the root cause of the high load and work on a solution to prevent it from occurring in the future.

Comment: welcome, aslong we don't know what specs we speak about, linux has not only load level 1 on a multiple cpu architecture. Each Cpu can lmhabdle a load level of 1 and each next an additional. moreover what iare the logs telling

Comment: @djdomi Updated my post. Typical load is 10% but on rare occasion, it increases to 100% for 15-20 minutes

Comment: you still did not provide the information, what is for you a 100% usage? a 20 core system can have 100% but that only means on a Linux system a load level of one, and not twenty or 5%overall or 100% on one core, I hope I could explain what is meaned here